Unable to find ReturnAuthorization.Model.js file
I want to override the setLines method in the ReturnAuthorization.Model.js file, but I can't find this file and don't know how the source code is written.
Where can I find this file? I don't know what methods and properties of ReturnAuthorizationModel are. I want to see the source code

The core code of SCA can be found in Netsuite's file cabinet, under the following path: "Web Site Hosting Files > Live Hosting Files > SSP Applications > NetSuite Inc. - SCA 20xx.x.x > Development > _Sources". You'll find a file called "SuiteCommerce Advanced.zip", which you can download and unzip, that contains what you're looking for.
The SSP application folder (NetSuite Inc. - SCA 20xx.x.x) path will vary depending on the version of SCA installed on the account.

The original "setLines" method for SCA 2022.2.2 is:
// @method setLines
// @param return_authorization
// @param lines
// @return {ReturnAuthorization.Model}
setLines: function(return_authorization, lines, transaction_lines) {
    let line_count = return_authorization.getLineItemCount('item');
    let add_line = true;
    let i = 1;

    while (i <= line_count) {
        const line_item_value = return_authorization.getLineItemValue('item', 'id', i);

        add_line = this.findLine(line_item_value, lines);
        if (add_line) {
            const transaction_line = _.findWhere(transaction_lines, {
                line: line_item_value
            });

            if (transaction_line) {
                return_authorization.setLineItemValue(
                    'item',
                    'rate',
                    i,
                    transaction_line.rate
                );
            }

            return_authorization.setLineItemValue('item', 'quantity', i, add_line.quantity);
            return_authorization.setLineItemValue(
                'item',
                'description',
                i,
                add_line.reason
            );

            i++;
        } else {
            const item_type = return_authorization.getLineItemValue('item', 'itemtype', i);
            if (item_type == 'GiftCert') {
                return_authorization.removeLineItem('item', i);
                line_count--;
            } else {
                return_authorization.setLineItemValue('item', 'quantity', i, 0);

                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}

The best way to change the code is to extend this method using a before or after event. Overriding the code should be the last option.
You can check how to extend a method in this link.

Thank you very much for your answer. Your answer is very helpful to me. Thank you
